# How to break this circular dependency

Tags: c#, circular-dependency

I have two classes (Room, Exit) that I think should depend on each other but that causes circular dependency which is a bad thing from what I read.

```
//problem
public class Game
{
   public List<Room> Rooms {get; set;}
}

public class Room
{
   public Exit Exit {get; set;}
}

public class Exit
{
   public Room NextRoom {get; set;}
}

//Here is my solution

public class Game
{
   public List<Room> Rooms {get; set;}

   public Room GetNextRoom(Exit exit)
   {
      //Loops through the rooms list and compares Room.Id by Exit.NextRoomId and returns it
   }
}
public class Room
{
   public Exit Exit {get; set;}
}

public class Exit
{
   public string NextRoomId {get;set;}
}
```

My question is if my solution is somewhat right or if there is another better solution to this problem. This breaks the circular dependency but makes it ugly when declaring the Exit object as it "references" the Room object by a string.

Keep in mind that I would like to not implement an Interface or Eventhandlers which I read is basically just a band-aid on the problem and can cause problems in the future.

Comment: Rule of thumb to know if you need inheritance (what you call dependence), or composition (your current solution), ask yourself : Is the exit *a part of* a room (composition). Or is the exit *a kind of* room  (inheritance)?

Comment: I am really curious as to how `Eventhandlers` could be used in any of this. Can someone show my the band-aid with `Eventhandlers`?

Comment: why do you think that these dependencies are bad? It's absolutely okay that a room knows its exits and every exist knows the rooms next to it.

Comment: Can only agree with @MakePeaceGreatAgain don't see an issue in your "problem".

Comment: The only issue here is that an exit may have a left and a right room, not just a *next* one.

Comment: And a room multiple exits.

Comment: @Irwene Well I guess its a part of a room but at the same time its a part of another room and this thinking got me into this mess. There must be some other way of implementing this than just having two objects depend on each other or my solution since its really ugly when declaring the Exit object.

Comment: @jw9832hds Let's turn the problem around then. Does the Exit have specific properties ? Or is it just the room(s) accessible from the one you are declaring ? If you are in the second case, couldn't you declare it like this : `public List<Room> Exits {get; set;} = new()`

Comment: It would be better to avoid dependencies in both directions (up & down). Better to have all dependencies pointing in the same direction. In this case: why has Exit has to know Room?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain Well I had it like that when I started but then when I wanted to serialize the object to save it to a file I ran into an exception caused by the objects that referenced each other... So I googled the problem and read that its apparently wrong to do it like that and that the best solution is to rethink completely and my solution is what I ended up with.

Comment: @johey Well how do I know which room to go to after the player exits the current room

Comment: @jw9832hds There are some serialization libraries that support circular dependencies: NEwtonsoft.Json being one of them. Do note, that you could have different representations for serialization and execution (eg: list the adjacent rooms by id when serializing, and reference the adjacent rooms directly when you're just executing)

Comment: @Irwene Newtonsoft.Json is exactly what I'm using. Exit has other properties yes.

"(eg: list the adjacent rooms by id when serializing, and reference the adjacent rooms directly when you're just executing)" I think I tried this already. I don't Serialize objects that depend on each other and then when I Deserialize I find the correct object by id from a list.

Comment: @jw9832hds Did you try this: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/preservereferenceshandlingobject.htm

Comment: Oh and you might need this configuration too : https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReferenceLoopHandlingIgnore.htm (to handle loops)

Comment: I'm not sure why a exit would be its own class, a exit would just be a pointer to the next room or null if your at the end of the game assuming its a linear progression.

Comment: @markfila Well an Exit could have a Key for example so there is a little difference between Room and Exit. But basically I use Exit as a pointer to the next Room. Also a room can have multiple Exits to different Rooms etc...

Comment: you can just have a treasure object on the room if you need it to hold things like keys, gold etc.

Answer (score 3):

What you have is effectively a directed graph with cycles. Your model of this is correct - you can't get rid of the cycles.

However, you don't need a separate "Exit" class - you can represent the exits for each room with a `List<Room>` property called (say) `Exits`.

Aside: Because the exits are effectively "directed" (i.e. they point to the next room only) to represent a bidirectional exit between room 1 and room 2 you have to add each exit individually. That is, when adding an exit from room 1 to room 2, you must also add an exit from room 2 to room 1 (unless the exits are one-way, of course).

You can use `Newtonsoft.Json` to serialise and deserialise such a graph, accounting for circular references.

The key thing is that you need to specify the Json serialisation option `PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All`.

Another important fact is that you cannot have any constructors that set properties of the class - otherwise the serialisation/deserialisation will fail.

Here's a compilable console app to demonstrate how to do it properly:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var room1 = new Room { Name = "room1" };
            var room2 = new Room { Name = "room2" };
            var room3 = new Room { Name = "room3" };

            room1.Exits.Add(room2); room2.Exits.Add(room1);
            room2.Exits.Add(room3); room3.Exits.Add(room2);
            room3.Exits.Add(room1); room1.Exits.Add(room3);

            var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
            };

            var serialised   = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(room1, jsonSettings);
            var deserialised = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Room>(serialised, jsonSettings)!;

            Console.WriteLine(deserialised.Name);                   // "room1"
            Console.WriteLine(deserialised.Exits[0].Name);          // "room2"
            Console.WriteLine(deserialised.Exits[0].Exits[1].Name); // "room3"
        }
    }

    public sealed class Room
    {
        public string Name { get; init; }
        public List<Room> Exits { get; } = new ();
    }
}
```

Note that the printing out of "room3" uses `Exits[1]` because that's how it was wired up in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

if a exit has no other properties or any properties that a room wouldn't (which I don't know why a exit would be different than a room since a exit would just be a pointer to the next room or null if your at the end of the game) then I would just do this, where the room holds a reference to the next room. Note: This assumes a room has only one exit, if there are multiple see mathews answer.

```
    public class Game
    {
        public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    }

    public class Room
    {
        public int RoomNumber { get; set; }
        public Room Exit { get; set; }
    }
```

you can then use it like this

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.Rooms = new List<Room>();

        Room firstRoom = new Room();
        Room exit = new Room();
        firstRoom.RoomNumber = 1;
        exit.RoomNumber = 2;

        firstRoom.Exit = exit;

        game.Rooms.Add(firstRoom);

        foreach(Room room in game.Rooms)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Room:" + room.RoomNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("Exit:" + room.Exit.RoomNumber);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```